# API Usage by User not shown

Tags: wso2

I try to connect wso2 api manager (1.6.0) with wso2 bam(2.4.0) using documentation instructions. I see the statistics in Api Manager Publisher but i can't see "API Usage by User". In log file of the Api Manager I have the following exception. Have someone any idea?

Thanks
Stefano

[2014-01-21 11:52:14,551] ERROR - APIProviderHostObject Error while invoking APIUsageStatisticsClient for ProviderAPIUsage
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.exception.APIMgtUsageQueryServiceClientException: Error occurred while querying from JDBC database
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.queryBetweenTwoDaysForAPIUsageByUser(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:1211)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.getAPIUsageByUser(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:313)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_getAPIUsageByUser(APIProviderHostObject.java:2146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c1._c_getAPIUsageByUser_6(/publisher/modules/statistics/usage.jag:147)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c1.call(/publisher/modules/statistics/usage.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c0._c_anonymous_11(/publisher/modules/statistics/module.jag:25)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.statistics.c0.call(/publisher/modules/statistics/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/ajax/stats.jag:153)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/ajax/stats.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/ajax/stats.jag:4)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/ajax/stats.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/ajax/stats.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.stats.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/stats/ajax/stats.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "CONTEXT" must be in the GROUP BY list; SQL statement:
SELECT API, API_VERSION, VERSION, USERID, SUM(TOTAL_REQUEST_COUNT) AS TOTAL_REQUEST_COUNT, CONTEXT FROM API_REQUEST_SUMMARY WHERE time BETWEEN '2014-01-20' AND '2014-01-22' GROUP BY API, API_VERSION, USERID ORDER BY TOTAL_REQUEST_COUNT DESC LIMIT 10 [90016-140]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:327)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:167)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:144)
        at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.updateAggregate(ExpressionColumn.java:148)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryGroup(Select.java:335)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryWithoutCache(Select.java:574)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Query.query(Query.java:241)
        at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:80)
        at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:132)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:76)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.APIUsageStatisticsClient.queryBetweenTwoDaysForAPIUsageByUser(APIUsageStatisticsClient.java:1193)
        ... 63 more

Comment: Isn't the stack trace is forward enough? It says that Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "CONTEXT" must be in the GROUP BY list; So just include the CONTEXT column in GROUP BY clause and check.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that your database contains the correct tables and indexes for WSO@ AM and WSO2 BAM? The error point to an incorrect query. If the database is correct, then it looks like the contructed query is wrong and you should ask WSO2 to create and issue/bug.

```
Column "CONTEXT" must be in the GROUP BY list;
SQL statement: 
SELECT API, API_VERSION, VERSION, USERID, SUM(TOTAL_REQUEST_COUNT) AS TOTAL_REQUEST_COUNT, CONTEXT 
FROM API_REQUEST_SUMMARY 
WHERE time BETWEEN '2014-01-20' AND '2014-01-22' 
GROUP BY API, API_VERSION, USERID 
ORDER BY TOTAL_REQUEST_COUNT DESC LIMIT 10 [90016-140]
```

Comment: I use the h2 embedded Database so i think there is no problem in creating Tables and Indexing. And in this case the error should be Table NOT FOUND. thanks

Comment: Looks like a bug IMHO, did try to clean up all the tmp and cach dirs of the h2 database and startup with -Dsetup option?